# Magento 2 - Delete Product Images Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, product-images, cron

I seem to have an issue deleting all images programatically from configurable products. I know the bad practice way that works fine on simple products

```
 $imageProcessor = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor');
                        $images = $p->getMediaGalleryImages();
                        if(count($images) > 0) {
                            foreach ($images as $child) {
                                $imageProcessor->removeImage($p, $child->getFile());
                            }
                        }

                        try{
                            $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $p->getMediaGalleryEntries();
                            if($existingMediaGalleryEntries != null) {
                                foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
                                    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
                                }

                                $p->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
                                $p = $this->productRepository->save($p);
                                $p->save();
                            }
                        }catch(\Exception $e)
                        {
                            $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error  >> cant save product '.$e->getMessage());
                            $this->getLogger()->error(print_r($message, true));
                        }
```

Using the above on a configurable product however is not working so i tried the below, in matching the mock tests in catalog product

```
   $imageProcessor = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement');
        foreach($p->getMediaGalleryEntries() as $key => $entry)
        {
            $imageProcessor->remove($p->getSku(), $entry->getId());
        }

        try {

            $p = $this->productRepository->save($p);
            $p->save();

        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error  >> cant save product '.$e->getMessage());
            $this->getLogger()->error(print_r($message, true));
        }
```

this is causing lock waits on the database and just stopping the crons from continuing to execute.

UPDATE:

Still no joy, im going to have to assume this is a bug

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delete the images i ended up doing the following. Unsetting the gallery image and also removing the imgae by file. then physically removing the image from the filesystem.

```
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $p->getMediaGalleryEntries();
                        if(is_array($existingMediaGalleryEntries)) {
                            foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
                                unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
                                $image = $entry->getFile();
                                $imageProcessor->removeImage($p, $image);
                                $image = 'pub/media/catalog/product' . $image;
                                if(file_exists($image)) {
                                    unlink($image);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $p->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
                        try {

                            $p = $this->productRepository->save($p);
                        }catch(\Exception $e)
                        {
                            $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Falied Delete Image Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' line ' . $e->getLine());
                            $this->getLogger()->error(print_r($message, true));
                        }
```

And then to create images programatically

```
protected function getContentObject($fileName)
    {

        if ($this->io->fileExists($fileName)) {
            $content = $this->imageContentFactory->create();
            $content->setName(strtolower(basename($fileName)));
            $content->setBase64EncodedData(base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileName)));
            $content->setType($this->mime->getMimeType($fileName));

            return $content;
        }

        return null;
    }

 public function importSingle(array $item)
    {
        if ($content = $this->getContentObject($item['image'])) {
            try {
                $product = $this->productRepository->get($item['sku']);
            }catch(\Exception $e)
            {
                return false;
            }

            $entries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
            $type = $item['types'];
            foreach ($entries as $lentry) {
                if (basename($lentry->getFile()) === $content->getName()) {
                   $entry = $lentry;
                   $type = array_unique(array_merge($type, $lentry->getTypes()));
                }
            }

            if (!isset($entry)) {
                $entry = $this->attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory->create();
            }

            $entry->setContent($content);
            $entry->setMediaType('image');
            $entry->setDisabled(false);
            $entry->setTypes($type);

            $entries[] = $entry;
            $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($entries);

            try {

                $p = $this->productRepository->save($product);

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Falied newname Product Image Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' line ' . $e->getLine());
                $this->getLogger()->info(print_r($message, true));

                $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error  >> File Newname Doesnt Exist: ' . $item['image']);
                $this->getLogger()->info(print_r($message, true));
                return false;
            }

            return $p;

        }else {
            $message = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error  >> File Newname Doesnt Exist: ' . $item['image']);
            $this->getLogger()->info(print_r($message, true));
            return false;
        }

        return false;


    }
```